# An interesting problem which I think only needs elementary number theory

Tags: prime-numbers, integer-programming, integer-sequences

### A problem about elementary number theory

> While writing my paper, I came across the following problem:
>   (all the discussion assume that $q$ is prime and $\alpha $ is a positive integer. ) We first ask :given an integer $\alpha$, can we always find a prime $q$ such that $q-\alpha $ divides $\alpha^{2}-\alpha$?
>   For this , I have already known that: for certain form of $\alpha$, no such $q$ can be found. Actually we have the following
>
> **Proposition 1:** If $\alpha =2p+1 $, and $p$ is prime such that $p \equiv 11  \;\text{or} \; 41 \pmod {60}$ , then no prime $q$ satisfy  $q-\alpha $ divides $\alpha^{2}-\alpha$.

**Proof of Prop1**:

Let $\alpha=2p+1 $, $p$ is a prime and  $p \equiv 11  \;\text{or} \; 41 \pmod {60}$, we next prove by contradiction that there doesn't exits prime $q$, such that  $q-\alpha $ divides $\alpha^{2}-\alpha$.

**Note  that**   $q=2$ is impossible , since  $2-\alpha | \alpha^{2}-\alpha$ imply $\alpha=0,1,3,or \;4$ all contradicts our assumption. We next assume that $q $ is an odd prime.
Since $q |\alpha \; \text{or} \; q\nmid \alpha$,we have two cases:

**Case 1**  :$ q\nmid \alpha$

In this case $gcd(q-\alpha,\alpha)=gcd(q,\alpha)=1$.  So $ q-\alpha $ divides $\alpha^{2}-\alpha=\alpha(\alpha-1)$ imply $q-\alpha |\alpha-1=2p$.Thus $q=(2p+1)\pm1,(2p+1)\pm2,(2p+1)\pm p,(2p+1)\pm 2p$. However when $p \equiv 11  \;\text{or} \; 41 \pmod {60}$,all the above form of $q$ can't be prime.

**Case 2**$  :q|\alpha$

Suppose $\alpha=rq$. Since $q-\alpha|\alpha^{2}-\alpha$, we have $q-\alpha|\alpha^{2}-\alpha=\alpha^2-q^2+q-\alpha+q^2-q$. So $q-\alpha|q^2-q$,namely $q-rq|q^2-q$,which imply $r-1|q-1$. But $\alpha=2p+1=rq=r(q-1)+r$,  so $2p=r(q-1)+r-1$ .Thus we get $r-1|2p$, so $r=2,3,p+1,2p+1$.  Note that $\alpha=2p+1 =rq$ is odd ,so $r$ must also be odd. Only $r=3,2p+1$ are possible .
If $r=2p+1$,then $r=2p+1=\alpha=rq$, which is impossible since $q$ is a prime.
If $r=3$, then $2p+1=3q\equiv 0\pmod 3$, which imply $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.This contradicts with $p \equiv 11  \;\text{or} \; 41 \pmod {60}$.

---

**My question** is what can we say if we replace $\alpha^2-\alpha$ by  $\alpha^3-\alpha$ , or more generally by  $\alpha^l-\alpha$ ( $l\geq 3$ is an integer). Given an integer $\alpha $, can we always find a prime $q$ such that $q-\alpha |\alpha^3-\alpha$ . I wrote a computer program to test all $\alpha\leq2000$ and found that for every $1\leq\alpha<1291$ we can find  a prime $q$ such that $q-\alpha|\alpha^3-\alpha $, $1291 $ is the first $\alpha $ that we can't find $q$ satisfying  $q-\alpha|\alpha^3-\alpha $. When we enlarge the scope of  $\alpha$, we can find more $\alpha $ for which no prime $q$ can be found.

Instinctively, I feel that for any $l\geq 2$ there exists infinity many $\alpha$ such that we can't find prime $q$ which makes $q-\alpha |\alpha^l-\alpha$. To prove that I think we need to provide  a certain form of $\alpha$ (just like the above case $\alpha =2p+1,p \equiv 11  \;\text{or} \; 41 \pmod {60}$ for $\alpha^2-\alpha$), I did my best but  I still don't know how to construct the form. If my intuition is wrong,how to prove that there are only finitely many such $\alpha$.If you are good at such problem, please do have  a try. I desperately need your help, thank you !

**REMARK**  Someone has point out that I was wrong in saying: $1291 $ is the first $\alpha $ that we can't find $q$ satisfying  $q-\alpha|\alpha^3-\alpha $.
Actually $\alpha=21362$ should be the first counter example! With this fact,it seems that the form of $\alpha$ can be more difficult to find than I previously imagined. However, I still don't think there are finitely such $\alpha$.

Comment: Which factor of $182^3 - 182$ is of the form $q-182$ with $q$ prime?

Comment: just take q=179

Comment: Sorry, I was just looking at positive factors.

Comment: $1297-1291=6$ divides $1291^3-1291$ and $1297$ is prime.

Comment: OTOH $\alpha = 21362$ seems to be a genuine example.

Comment: Previously posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917847/an-interesting-problem-which-only-needs-elementary-number-theory

Comment: OMG, you are  right ! My program has a run overflow mistake, I corrected that and found you are right :$\alpha=21362$ is the first counterexample! but i didn't find any more. thank you very much!@FelipeVoloch

Comment: $21362,\; 27148,\; 34412,\; 35662,\; 37228,\; 37352,\; 37922,\;\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots 52796,\; 53708,\; 53768,\; 57360,\; 57362,\; \ldots$.  Not (yet) in OEIS.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts !  I think it's quite possible that only  part of the sequence in OEIS,the whole sequence can't be. @RobertIsrael

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about only using elementary number theory but here is an approach using the Bateman-Horn conjecture. Maybe one can get by with a bit less using sieve methods but I will leave that to the specialists.

Let $\alpha$ be of the form $210n+160$ where $n$ an integer and assume that $\alpha/10 = 21n+16, (\alpha -1)/3 = 70n+53$ and $(\alpha +1)/7 = 30n+23$ are all prime. The Bateman-Horn conjecture implies that this happens for infinitely many $n$ with the expected frequency. For this $\alpha$ to work we need that $\alpha + d$ and $\alpha - d$ are not prime for $d$ running through the $128$ positive divisors of $\alpha^3-\alpha$. (The primality conditions are to restrict the number of factors of $\alpha^3-\alpha$). Now, the frequency of the $n$'s for which one of these $256$ conditions fail is lower, again by Bateman-Horn (it's possible that the required upper bound can be proved unconditionally). So this gives the required examples.

The first few values of $\alpha$ obtained this way are $496390, 1169230, 1239790, 3806410, 4176430$.

Comment: It's really a great idea to think in that way, which I believe can be improved.Thanks a lot